# Ubuntu isn't displaying on two of my monitors

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I have four monitors for my computer, two plugged into my GPU and two plugged into my motherboard. The two monitors that are plugged into my GPU and displaying and the ones plugged into my motherboard are just black and aren't recognized when I go into my display settings. Any idea how to fix this? (I'm doing the "Try Ubuntu Before Installing" thing before I install completely so I'd like to fix it before I install it)

(GPU is 1080 if it matters)